# "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'from_user'" message change from Instructions to Welcome

Tags: telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I could need some help. Im trying to code a telegram bot. When a user starts to interact with the bot via /start he receives a Welcome message with to inline keyboard buttons. The first button hasn't a function yet. But the second button changes the Welcome message to an instruction message that also has an inline keyboard button ("BACK"). When the user presses this button the instruction message should change back to the welcome message. That didn't worked out, so I decided to leave it without this "going back to start" function and just give him the Callback "you chose back". But every time I try get it run I receive the same attributeError.

Here is my code so far:

```
from telegram import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, CallbackQueryHandler

# Ihr Bot-Token
TOKEN = "Bot_Token"

# Ein globaler Wert, um den Zustand des Bots zu verfolgen
START, INSTRUCTIONS = range(2)

def start(update, context):
    user = update.message.from_user
    
    # Text der Willkommensnachricht
    welcome_message = """⚜️ **PayEscrowBOT** ⚜️ v.1.1
#1 Automated Telegram Escrow Service

Welcome to **PayEscrowBOT**™️. This bot provides a safe escrow service for your business on Telegram. Never get ripped again, The bot secures your funds throughout the deal. If you have any issues, kindly type /contact and an arbitrator will join the group chat within 24 hours.

 **ESCROW FEE:**
5% if over $100
5$ if under $100

☑️ **DEALS DONE:** 1200
‍⚖️ **DISPUTES HANDLED:** 280

 **Declare the seller or buyer with** /seller or /buyer [BTC/LTC ADDRESS] (**Your BTC/LTC address =** [BTC/LTC ADDRESS])

 Type /menu **to summon a menu with all bot's features**"""

    # Erstes Inline-Keyboard
    keyboard1 = [[InlineKeyboardButton("❓ WHAT IS ESCROW", callback_data="what_is_escrow"),
                 InlineKeyboardButton("ℹ️ INSTRUCTIONS", callback_data="instructions")]]
    
    # Inline-Keyboard-Markup für das erste Keyboard
    reply_markup1 = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard1)

    # Senden der Willkommensnachricht mit dem Inline-Keyboard
    update.message.reply_markdown(welcome_message, reply_markup=reply_markup1)
    
    # Setzen des Bots in den START-Zustand
    context.user_data["state"] = START

def instructions(update, context):
    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()
    
    # Nachricht mit den Anweisungen
    instructions_message = """ INSTRUCTIONS

1️⃣ Add the bot to a new Group Chat with buyer + seller

2️⃣ Declare the seller with /seller [BTC/LTC ADDRESS]
        Replace [BTC/LTC ADDRESS] with receive wallet

3️⃣ Declare the buyer with /buyer [BTC/LTC ADDRESS]
        Replace [BTC/LTC ADDRESS] with refund wallet

4️⃣ Generate a wallet with /generate

5️⃣ Buyer sends agreed amount to generated BTC wallet

6️⃣ Check balance with /balance

7️⃣ Seller releases product / service to buyer when balance is confirmed

8️⃣ When buyer is satisfied, release payment with /release
    The seller can also /refund the buyer.

9️⃣ If any issues, contact arbitrator with /contact

❗️ For video example, type /video

☎️ If you need help, type /contact [INVITE LINK TO GROUP]
Replace [INVITE LINK TO GROUP] with the invite link of the group chat."""

    # Inline-Keyboard für den Zurück-Button
    back_keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton("⬅️ BACK", callback_data="back")]]
    back_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(back_keyboard)

    # Senden der Anweisungsnachricht mit dem Zurück-Button
    query.edit_message_text(text=instructions_message, reply_markup=back_markup)
    
    # Setzen des Bots in den INSTRUCTIONS-Zustand
    context.user_data["state"] = INSTRUCTIONS

def back(update, context):
    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()
    
    if context.user_data["state"] == INSTRUCTIONS:
        # Zurück zur Willkommensnachricht mit den Optionen
        start(update, context)

def button(update, context):
    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()

    if query.data == "instructions":
        instructions(update, context)
    elif query.data == "back":
        start(update, context)
    else:
        query.edit_message_text(text=f"Du hast {query.data} ausgewählt")

def main():
    updater = Updater(token=TOKEN, use_context=True)
    dp = updater.dispatcher

    # Definieren Sie den /start-Handler
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))

    # Definieren Sie den Callback-Handler für die Inline-Keyboards
    dp.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(button))

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is the Error message I get:

```
No error handlers are registered, logging exception.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/philippalbrecht/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/telegram/ext/dispatcher.py", line 340, in process_update
    handler.handle_update(update, self, check, context)
  File "/Users/philippalbrecht/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/telegram/ext/handler.py", line 119, in handle_update
    return self.callback(update, context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/philippalbrecht/Desktop/Telegram/Telegram_escrow", line 101, in button
    back(update, context)
  File "/Users/philippalbrecht/Desktop/Telegram/Telegram_escrow", line 92, in back
    start(update, context)
  File "/Users/philippalbrecht/Desktop/Telegram/Telegram_escrow", line 11, in start
    user = update.message.from_user
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'from_user'
```

Can someone help to fix this error?

Thank you!

In the first place I would like the bot to change back from the instruction message to the welcome message, so that the user can choose again from the first two inline keyboard buttons. Because this didn't worked, I just want a simple change from the instructions to "you chose back". But I always receive this error.

Answer (score 0):

The error message simply indicates that `update.message is None`. The traceback also indicates that the error happens in the function `button`, which calls the function `start` internally. Since `button` is registered as callback function to a `CallbackQueryHandler`, it will only ever see updates with `update.message` being `None` and instead with `update.callback_query` being non-`None`.

You might want to use `update.effective_user` instead.

---

Note that you're using PTB v13.x or older, which is no longer supported. I encourage you to upgrade you code to v20.x.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.